# How to reset terminator terminal emulator configuration?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal-emulator, terminator

I messed up terminator, I tried to use some commands in the preferences and now it doesn't work anymore, it starts and exits immediately, I tried reinstalling it using synaptic manager, but that didn't work either. I searched didn't find anything.

I still can use xterm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The settings for most programs are kept either in "dot folders" in your `$HOME` directory (for example, `$HOME/.libreoffice`) or in your `$HOME/.config/` directory.

`terminator` uses the latter approach so any changes you made to your preferences would be saved in `$HOME/.config/terminator`. Deleting or renaming that folder and then launching `terminator` again should solve your problems (and also lose any changes you have made, including the ones you may want to keep):

```
mv $HOME/.config/terminator $HOME/.config/terminator_old
```